# Python: argsort in descending order for 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to sort by the first column in descending order an array. To be specific my code is:

```
>>> x = np.array([[2, 3], [1998,5], [1998,7]])
>>> x = x[np.argsort(x[:,0])]
```

but the output is

```
array([[   2,    3],
       [1998,    5],
       [1998,    7]])
```

but I need it in descending order. Can someone explain me how to do that?

EDIT:  @Babyburger suggested this solution :

```
x = x[np.argsort(x[:,0])][::-1]
```

that give

```
array([[1998,    7],
       [1998,    5],
       [   2,    3]])
```

it could be fine, but i would like that where the value on the first column is the same, the order is not changed. So the output would be

```
array([[1998,    5],
       [1998,    7],
       [   2,    3]])
```

is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Try x = x[np.argsort(x[:,0])[::-1]]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this particular requirement you can use python's `sorted` which is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability):

```
a =  np.array([[2, 3], [1998,5], [1998,7]])
res = np.array(sorted(a, key= lambda x: -x[0]))
```

it does: use the first element of each row for comparison (by `lambda` accessor) and negate it for decreasing order. By stability, the rows will preserve order if the first element is the same

ouput:

```
[[1998    5]
 [1998    7]
 [   2    3]]
```

EDIT: btw if you wanted to sort by the following columns whenever the preceeding ones are identical (all of the same ordering):

```
a =  np.array([[2, 3], [1998,5], [1998,7]])
res = np.array(sorted(a, key=lambda x:(-x).tolist()))
```

this converts the rows to lists and then uses [sequence comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). Note in this example it will be sorted decreasingly (hence `(-x)`)

Comment: I like that you mention that python `sorted` is stable! To clarify to others; this is not the case with `np.argsort` when used with default parameters (`kind="quicksort"`), but is when used with `kind="mergesort"`